# getbundle(basename) ResourceBundle java

Tags: java

What is basename in ResourceBundle I have example and files like this

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Main 
{
      public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception 
      {
          ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("RresourcesDynamic");
          System.out.println(rb.getString("title"));
      }
}
  ///here when i run this program i am getting exception like this
  //Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't                bundle     for base name RresourcesDynamic, locale en_US



  //what is basename what i have to mention in this argument is this file name or what?
```

ResourcesDynamic.properties----title=leo

Thanks in advance

Comment: Question is unclear. Are you having problems loading the resource bundle file?

Comment: what you want to asked?? are you asking about how function work or something else?

Answer (score 1):

RresourcesDynamic (in source) != ResourcesDynamic (filename)

[Full explanation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29)

Short: ResourceBundle.properties (usual key=value properties file) must exists in *class path*